# Using CI_PIPELINE_IID variable, how can I navigate back to the corresponding commit in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to use the CI_PIPELINE_IID variable from the gitlab predefined variables, which I found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference, for a build version in my project, and I need to be able to use this variable to go back to the commit where it was generated. Is there a way to use this variable to go back to the specific pipeline/commit where it was generated?

Thanks

I tried to find out in the documentation, and other topics and couldn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Having the `CI_PIPELINE_IID` value at hand, you can make a call to GitLab's API to fetch data about the pipeline, thus including the commit sha that generated it. The documentation about the pipelines' api can be seen [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline).

An example would look like:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_IID"`

And that will return you a JSON object with the pipelines' data. You can then use a tool like `jq` to easily extract its related sha:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_IID" | jq .sha`